# Can't install VirtualBox on Debian 9

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox

Hi' I want to install some VM on my Debian but the install fails I tried with two .deb (my pc is x64 so I tried to install first the amd64 version)

- **virtualbox-5.2_5.2.0-118431-Debian-stretch_amd64.deb**
- **virtualbox-5.2_5.2.0-118431-Debian-stretch_i386.deb**

output:

```
~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.2_5.2.0-118431-Debian-stretch_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 359023 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-5.2_5.2.0-118431-Debian-stretch_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-5.2 (5.2.0-118431~Debian~stretch) over (5.2.0-118431~Debian~stretch) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-5.2:
 virtualbox-5.2 depends on libqt5core5a (>= 5.7.0).
 virtualbox-5.2 depends on libqt5gui5 (>= 5.4.0).
 virtualbox-5.2 depends on libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2).
 virtualbox-5.2 depends on libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2).
 virtualbox-5.2 depends on libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.7.0).
 virtualbox-5.2 depends on libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0).

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-5.2 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-5.2
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox

Answer (score 6):

To install virtualbox , run the following commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

add the following line:

Debian **Stretch** :

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib
```

Debian **Buster** ( use the `bionic` codename) :

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
```

Then:

```
curl -O https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc
sudo apt-key add oracle_vbox_2016.asc
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualbox-6.0
```

[Debian docs](https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox#Debian_9_.22Stretch.22)

Comment: Yes. This is also the "official" way to do it: https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox#Debian_9_.22Stretch.22

Comment: Works on Debian 10 (Buster)

Answer (score 3):

You are having dependency issue. Run

```
# apt install -f
```

To fix dependencies

Or use apt directly

```
# apt install ./virtualbox-5.2_5.2.0-118431-Debian-stretch_amd64.deb
```

Which will fix dependency issues too.